# Selecting a random color in java

Tags: java, iphone, objective-c, xcode, porting

I have an iPhone version of my application which is using a bit of code for setting up colors.

```
((rand() % 176) * 80) / 256.0f
```

I am new to `objective c` so I can't figure out how this is working. I want to make exact copy of this for Android in `Java`.

In Java we usually use `Random()` . How am i suppose to implement this above function using `Random r = Random();`

Comment: It's really straightforward. What part don't you understand? The line of code you posted is straight C, there's no Objective-C in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent one-liner in Java would be:

```
((new Random().nextInt() % 176) * 80) / 256.0f;
```

More about the random class on the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Obviously you should not create a new instance of `Random` each time.

```
Random r = new Random();
// call r.nextInt() each time you need a new random integer
double color = ((r.nextInt() % 176) * 80) / 256.0f;
```

Comment: There's no reason to construct a new `Random` object each time you want a new random value.

Comment: one-liner, but would not be efficient if have to generate multiple random numbers otherwise its fine.

Comment: @TedHopp I edited the answer, it seemed obvious at the time I wrote it, maybe not for a beginner.

Comment: @HarmeetSingh Oh thank you I didn't knew that... MOTO. I was talking about the OP, not me.

Answer (score 2):

In Android, I'd first initialize a variable `rand = new Random()`. Then I would write your expression as:

```
rand.nextInt(176) / 3.2f
```

(Note that `80 / 256.0 == 1 / 3.2`.) I would only assign a value to `rand` once and reuse the same `Random` object each time I needed a new color.

After a little back-of-the-envelope work, it seems that your original code is just a fancy way of computing a random float value uniformly distributed between 0 and 55.0f. Thus, a much simpler way of doing the same thing would be:

```
rand.nextFloat(55)
```

The only disadvantage of this is that it doesn't resemble the original code very closely (although it will behave the same).